# Why setcookie function redirecting to home page in wordpress?

Tags: plugin-development, cookies

I have build a plugin in which i have used setcookie like this :

```
function myFunctionAbc () {
$response = wp_remote_get('http://my/request/url/', array('timeout' => 240, 'decompress' => false));
$responseData = json_decode($response['body'], true);
setcookie('my_data', $response['body']);

return $responseData;
}
```

and in template file am doing this :

```
<?php
/* Template Name: custom results */

if (function_exists('myFunctionAbc')){
    $response = myFunctionAbc();
} else {
echo 'no data';
}
```

Now if i comment setcookie line, everything works fine but with setcookie, wordpress redirecting it to home page. I can't use init hook as i need data on some particular actions.

Note : I am using wordpress 4.6.1 and its working fine on my local system but having this issue on server.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the  Domain & other parameters also in cookie...

```
setcookie('cookie_name', cookie_val, time()+3600, COOKIEPATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, false);
```